# Forbidden Error

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions

I am trying to install the extension in magento 1.9.2.2.I am clicking the Magento Connect -> Magento Connect Manager is displaying error like this [image]

Any one help me..

Comment: Clear the cache and try it

Comment: what is the Url ?

Answer (score 2):

its just permission issue

give write permission to `downloader` folder located in your magento root

and your job is done

Comment: Thanks , I have change the permission of downloader permission 777 but still same error

Comment: change owner to `www:data`

Comment: @Murtuza Zabuawala i have change the owner permission also but still same error

Answer (score 1):

1. Logout your `admin` & `magento connect`
2. After that clear cache in `var/cache`

Then Login `admin` & `magento connect`

Comment: Still the same error